# Как объединить запрос по двум id mysql

Tags: php, mysql, связь

Есть таблица t1 в который хранится данные: имя, время и т.д.

```
id | name 
1  | данные 1
2  | данные 2
3  | данные 3
```

Есть вторая таблица t2 в которой лежит связь.

```
id | t1_id_1 | t1_id_2
1  | 1         | 2
2  | 1         | 3
```

Мне нужно получить такой ответ

```
1 - данные 1 \ данные 2
2 - данные 1 \ данные 3
```

Как выполнить такой запрос? Может вообще поменять структуру таблицы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это нормальная структура. Разве только удалить из таблицы связей поле id за ненадобностью. Пара ссылок на сущности - это отличный естественный первичный ключ.

Фокус лишь в том, чтобы приджойнить таблицу дважды и присвоить разные псевдонимы:

```
select t2.id, t1_1.name, t1_2.name 
from t2
  join t1 as t1_1 on t1_1.id=t1_id_1
  join t2 as t1_2 on t1_2.id=t2_id_1
```